# Cannot ping server behind wifi extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

I have a server connected to a wifi extender (too long/impractical to run Ethernet).
Topology:

**Modem/Router <--wireless--> wifi extender <--ethCable--> server**

The extender advertises an SSID, and if connected to it, I can access both the internet, and ping/connect to the server. This is as I would expect.

The **problem**: If I am connected to the SSID advertised by the modem router I can access the internet (as expected) but I can no longer ping my server.
Similarly, the server is not listed as a client by the modem router.

The server has a static ip address: 192.168.0.7 (no other conflicting ips)

The wifi extender has an ip assigned by the modem router : 192.168.0.2

To the best of my understanding I have everything on the same subnet (the wifi extender just bridges the two networks but does not create its own subnet). So regardless of which access point (modem router or wifi extender) I connect to I should still be on the same subnet, where all the devices are: yet I cannot ping the static ip of the server when I am not connected to the wifi extender access point.

What could be the issue ?